# Get device id in windows with c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem getting the id of the Windows device. He returns it to me empty. I don't know why that inconvenience.
My code:

```
productIdEdit.Text = RegHelper.readStringValue(RegistryValues.productIdKey(), RegistryValues.productIdValue());
```

With this line I call two classes with the values I need to search for.
RegHelper:

```
public static string readStringValue(string regKey, string regValue)
{
string result;
try
{
   result = (string)Registry.GetValue(regKey, regValue, "");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    result = ""; 
}
return result;
}
```

RegistryValues:

```
public static string productIdKey()
{
    return "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion";
}

public static string productIdValue()
{
    return "ProductId";
}
```

The program runs in administrator mode.

Comment: Any exception caught ?

Comment: My bet is : it tries to read the 32 bits branch `WOW6432Node`

Comment: What do they mean what they say? I'm a bit of a fool on this.

Comment: I must clarify that in some he obtains them to me, but in others he does not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
        using Microsoft.Win32;

        public static string getDeviceId()
        {

        string ret = string.Empty;
        RegistryKey regKey = null;

        try
        {
            var regDefault = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", false);
            ret = regDefault.GetValue("ProductId").ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ret = string.Format("Your error message");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (regKey != null)
                regKey.Close();
        }

        return ret;

    }
```

Hope it helps :).

Comment: Show me your mistake

Comment: could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Ok, so, the code first go to the specified registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion) using the statement :  Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey()// with the second parameter as false as we don't want to modifiy the registry.

Comment: You can also use Registry.CurrentUser for the HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Then it gets the value of ProductId Property from the registry which is the Device Id. Also, By using a finally block, you can clean up any resources that are allocated in a try block, and you can run code even if an exception occurs in the try block

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Comment: what kind of example? please elaborate.

Comment: what 'regKey' used for ?

Comment: don't you mean by replace 'regDefault' with 'regKey' ?